# Transaction Scope giving underlying connection failed to open

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

For LINQ i am using TransactionScope to handle transactions. When i execute the queries i get an exception.

> Underlying connection failed to Open.

and the inner exception is saying something about DTC. I read online that i will have to enable some service on the server. But i donot want to do that. How can i use transcactions without enabling DTC. My code is something like this

```
public void function1()
{
     using(TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope())
     {
         RunSomeSelectQueries();
         RunSomeInsertQueries();
         RunSomeUpdate Queries();

         t.Complete();
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the inner exception is saying something about DTC." - what about instead of "something aobut DTC" you proove you are capable of copy/pasting that?

Comment: You are trying to run a distributed transaction here and as such it is going to require the DTC so the answer is - you can't. One approach that would get around this would be to use a single connection rather than multiple contexts.

Comment: @TomTom the development PC's are only on intranet and i have to come outside my room to use internet. So, i guess you can understand my suituation.

Comment: @James i actually have single context but i don't understand why it is giving me the exception.

Comment: Old computer? I mean like XP? I Think Kernel Level Transactions were introduced with WIndows 7 - anything before that has the DTC from connection 1.

Comment: @Behroz are you using a single context *instance* though?

Comment: In the constructor i initialize only. Like entity = new ctdatabaseentities(); after that i am just using the entity object everywhere. I dont unserstand why i have a problem

Comment: And no matter what happens. First query executes fine but the second query is always giving exception.

Comment: Probably best that you show your code in it's entirety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serious problem in you tx handling that will push al ot of load into various levels.

- TransactioNScope is nice, but
- Calling methods that open separate connections WITHOUT NEED is bad.

Here is why:

- If a Tx has one connection, it is handled in the kernel as local transaciton scope.
- If you have multiple connections (transacted ressources) you need DTC.

And:

- DTC is much slower than just a connection, with a lot more load on the server (multiple open connections - they have to stay open until the transaction commits). Also that turns into a multi step commit - generally a lot of overhead and making things slower.

That generally is a "hey, I just use transactions" antipattern.

Properly you should make sure you only create one database connection UNLESS YOU NEED MORE THAN ONE (like multiple databases are involved) so that the transaction scope does not proppagate to the DTC for having multiple ressources.

Obviously you also should configure DTC correctly IF you need it, but again: in this case the real problem is that you abuse the transaction scope forcing a DTC propagation where none is actually needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was unable to solve the problem so, i got rid of Transaction scope. I used the normal transactions and they are working fine now.